# Series and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have a question about a sequence.
lets assume $a_n = {sin(\frac 1n)\over 3n}$
does the limit of the sequence $(-1)^na_n$ converge to zero?
I's pretty sure this is decreasing because of the derivative test which gives me a negative derivative and I believe it should be bounded at zero. But if it oscelates between negative and positive as n goes to infinity does it still converge at zero? Also can anyone tell me if my previous steps were wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: If you believe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$, then you may squeeze $-a_n \le (-1)^n a_n \le a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|a_n|\le |\frac{1}{3n}|$, which converges to zero, $a_n$ and $(-1)^n a_n$ also converge to zero, i.e. their limit is zero.

Note that the definition of convergence to zero for the sequence $a_n$ is that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find $N$ such that $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N$, so the changing sign has no effect.

Comment: cool I appreciate the answer. But to clarify what is the e looking symbol and what does it mean.

Comment: The $\epsilon$ symbol is one form of the Greek letter epsilon. It is conventionally used to indicate small numbers. Basically the definition of convergence says that if you think of any positive amount, no matter how small, there is a position in the sequence beyond which every value in the sequence is within that amount of the target. If you think of a smaller amount you have to go further along the sequence.